# different result from tex4ht vs. pdf when using macro call

Tags: urls, tex4ht

I have a small macro that I use to help me build some links.  This below is a very simplified version of the problem. Some links have `#` in the URL. So I had to escape `#` using `\#`.

This works ok in PDF generated. But when I compile to HTML, the dash before the `#` remains there and so in the HTML generated by tex4ht, the URL is not valid.

If I do not escape the `#` then latex complains.

The actual URL I am using an example is     https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fricas-devel

Here is MWE, with output by pdflatex and output by make4ht

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\addEntry}[1]
{%  
    \url{#1} 
}%

\begin{document}
Here is a link to a computer algebra FriCAS google news group:

\addEntry{https://groups.google.com/forum/\#!forum/fricas-devel}
\end{document}
```

Here is result in the PDF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the result from `make4ht foo.tex` (screen shot of the HTML page generated)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see that the `\` is stuck there. This means when I click on the link, it does not work. When I click on it, the Browser changes the link this

```
    https://groups.google.com/forum//#!forum/fricas-devel
```

So there is an extra `//` when only one should be there `/`  so I have to each time manually erase one `/` from the URL to make it work.

Here is the raw HTML generated by make4ht

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 11--><p class="noindent" >Here is a link to a computer algebra FriCAS google news group:
</p><!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >   <a 
href="https://groups.google.com/forum/\#!forum/fricas-devel" class="url" ><span 
class="cmtt-10x-x-109">https://groups.google.com/forum/\#!forum/fricas-devel</span></a> </p> 
</body></html>
```

I am using texlive 2016

```
make4ht -version
make4ht version 0.1b

which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/make4ht
```

How to fix this so that tex4ht will not keep the `\` in there link in the PDF?

Comment: At least with your MWE you can just use `#!` in the url with `pdflatex` and press enter when the `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.` messages show up. The document compiles fine.

Comment: @Skillmon  The build is done using Makefiles, so I can't really press enter and such manually as the build will stop otherwise when I am not on the terminal. But thanks for the information.

Comment: Then use the following in your Makefile's target (at least in the meantime): `pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode file.tex`

Comment: @Skillmon but would this not stop the build when a real error shows up? I have large tree and I want the build to stop on an error so I can fix it. If I tell the build to keep going, I will not see any errors that show. But I think a fix should be done at source level. I do not like these workarounds a problem.

Comment: Me neither. But since I don't know a proper solution atm. this workaround does the trick in the meantime...

Comment: apart from the catcode issue you are missing a `%` at end of line in your definition (the second `%` does nothing where you have it, and should be on the line above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think best solution would be to enable insertion of unescaped `#` character as parameter to your custom macro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\addEntry}[1]
{%  
  \expandafter\url\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}%
}%

\begin{document}
Here is a link to a computer algebra FriCAS google news group:

\addEntry{https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fricas-devel}
\end{document}
```

This works both with `pdflatex` and `tex4ht`:

[image]

Comment: Funny, I tried that (`\detokenize`) and it didn't work out... Maybe I was missing one `\expandafter` (I don't remember the exact code I tried).

Comment: @Skillmon I was actually quite surprised that it started to work with `\expandafter` :)

Comment: I was pretty sure it should work with `\expandafter` but was disappointed, that it didn't work (I think I only had the first one, which resulted in detokenizing `#1`...).

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to your problem, but I do not succeed in building it into `\addEntry`. The solution is to (locally) change the `\catcode` of `#`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\addEntry}[1]
{%  
    \url{#1} 
}%

\begin{document}
Here is a link to a computer algebra FriCAS google news group:

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=11
\addEntry{https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fricas-devel}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```